# Fragment back navigation with Mapview not working as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity in which two fragments are there. When the application loads, fragment A with a mapview is loaded by `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentA).commit();`

I have a side menu and when i select an item on it, the second fragment is loaded.

```
Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
fragmentB .setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB );
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

But when I press the back button from fragmentB, the app exits.

So I have added the below code to MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Now the fragment A loads, but the map is static and it is not animating the current location although I have the code to move camera to current location in onCreateView method(setUpMapIfNeeded() inside onCreateView())

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = mapView.getMap();
        }
        if(mMap!=null){
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(0, 0)).zoom(17).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }
```

All the lifecycle methods are getting called in fragmentA , but the mapview is not showing current location.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the Google Maps API. See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer.html).

Call `MapsInitializer.initialize(context);` before `mapView.getMap();`